# Simple Complex Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a solution to the differential equation $y'' = -y^3$?

For lesser powers there are obvious solutions, for example...
$y'' = -y\ \ \ \to \ \ \ y=\sin x$
$y'' = y \ \ \ \to \ \ \ y=e^x$
$y'' = -y^2\ \ \ \to \ \ \ y=\frac1x$
I don't think there's an easy way to solve my question though, or at least none that I can think of, because separate and integrate won't work, and the equation isn't linear so no characteristic equation fanciness will happen.

I just wanted to throw this out, and if a solution exists, or it is proven it can't exist, I'd greatly appreciate it!

**BTW, I already found one solution. I just want a way to solve it without blatant assumptions.** I assumed the solution would be of the form $y=a\cdot x^r$. Solving for variables in the equation led to the solution $y=\frac{\sqrt2}x$, but it's not a truly proper way to solve a differential equation. I just need a bit of help, or a push, or a shove if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that $y=\frac{\sqrt2}x$ is a solution ?

Comment: A hint: first, take $u(y)=y'(y)$, so $y''=\frac{du}{dx}= \frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dy}u$, and substitute it into the equation.

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{x}$ isn't a solution, but $\frac{\sqrt{-2}}{x}$ is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $y''$ is only a functionof $y$, the easiest "trick" is to multiply throughout by $y'$

$$ y'y'' = -y^3y' $$

then integrate to get

$$ \frac{y'^2}{2} = C - \frac{y^4}{4} $$

Solving for $y'$

$$ y' = \pm \sqrt{\frac{c-y^4}{2}}$$

which is separable. The solution does not have a closed form.

Comment: Yes, it does have a closed form, in terms of Jacobi elliptic function $\operatorname{sn}$, see [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%5Bx%5D%3D-(y%5Bx%5D)%5E3).

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha Pro gives $y(x)=\pm\sqrt{2}C\operatorname{sn}(Cx+D\mid-1)$.

Comment: @user539887 To clarify, I meant to say "in terms of elementary functions"